# Ubuntu 18.04 set custom icon for executable saved in ~/Desktop using command

Tags: desktop-icons

If I save an executable MyApp in ~/Desktop, I can right click on the icon, select Properties from menu.
In the Properties window I can now left click on the icon to open Select custom icon window.
Next I double click on the required .png file to use as custom icon and close Properties window.
This changes the executable's desktop icon to the selected custom .png file.

Is there a way to do the above procedure using bash shell commands?

The selected custom icon .png file doesn't appear to be saved in a MyApp.desktop file, so where is this setting saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information is saved in a binary file:

```
~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
```

You can not simply edit it, but use some `gio`-tools:

---

Check the attributes of one file:

```
gio info file
```

Change attributes:

```
gio set file attribute value
```

---

So in your case to change the custom icon:

```
gio set ~/Desktop/MyApp metadata::custom-icon file:///path/to/icon.png
```

To remove the attribute, use `-t unset`:

```
gio set -t unset ~/Desktop/MyApp metadata::custom-icon
```

---

In earlier Ubuntu Versions (e.g. 16.04) the commands are `gvfs-info` instead of `gio info` and `gvfs-set-attribute` instead of `gio set`), but work exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you pLumo.

Comment: To update desktop icon display, I used  'touch ~/Desktop/MyApp'  after using  'gio set'  command.